# as3 adding var names together to get object name

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I need to add two vars together to get an existing var name already declared.

```
var Tweet1:String;


//code called later in function
var num = 1;
output.text = Tweet+num; // This does not work
```

Comment: I have 20 tweets and each one is called Tweet1, Tweet2 etc... but I am getting the var dynamically so I want the "Tweet1" to be my final result. or Tweet2 etc.. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next syntax: `this["Tweet"+num]`

Comment: That didn't work. I tried this: output.text = "Tweet"+daNum; and I got the right text to display "Tweet1" but Tweet1 is already a string name so I need the actual Tweet1 content (example: Hello, I am a tweet) and not the string name "Tweet1"

Comment: @PapaDeBeau What exactly "didn't work"? What error message it gives?

Comment: Thanks. This was the error I got|| TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null. at flash.text::TextField/set text()

Comment: Wait.. I think the value of Tweet1 is not loaded yet, this is why. Hold on. :)